# How do i round an address down to a multiple of 16

Tags: c

Given an `unsigned char *x`, I need to round the address that `*x` points to down to a multiple of  16.  Such as `0x7fff5fbff7fc` down to `0x7fff5fbff7f0`. I've tried to shift it using:

```
x >> 4;
x << 4;
```

Also tried

```
x >>= 4;
x <<= 4;
```

but it won't allow me to do this considering it is not an integer.  Any advice?

Comment: (as in `(char *)((uintptr_t)(x) & ~(uintptr_t)(15))`...)

Comment: Im getting undeclared identifier uintptr_t

Comment: By the way, your `x >>= 4; x <<= 4;` approach would have worked if you had introduced a temporary variable of type `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @davidS You have to import a certain header file to access that type. IIRC it's `<stdint.h>` but it's trivial to google it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am allowed to add any headers for this program.  The goal of it is to make it a multiple of 16 so i can print out 0x7fff5fbff7f0 then 0x7fff5fbff00 then 0x7fff5fbff81 etc,

Comment: @davidS "I'm not sure if I am allowed to add any headers for this program." - ***???***

Comment: I mean that if there is any way for me to accomplish rounding down to 16, without including other headers, then that would be most helpful.

Comment: @davidS You certainly **do want** to use `uintptr_t` since it's guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer without loss of data when performing type conversions. If you don't want to include a header file (I still don't understand why that is such a big problem), you can just go ahead, search for the definition of `uintptr_t` in `<stdint.h>` and use that type directly, but your code isn't going to be portable if you take that approach.

Comment: @H2CO3 if this is a class question, portability isn't a concern.

Comment: Okay. so to make sure i understand your code correctly. (char *)((uintptr_t)(x) converts x to a uintptr_t.  and ~(uintptr_t)(15) converts 0x0000..0F to 0xfffff..f0.  then I use & on the 2 of them to simply change the last hexidecimal of x to a 0?

Comment: @Alex This doesn't seem like a typical assignment question, though.

Comment: @davidS Yes, that's exactly how it works.

Answer (score 7):

```
(unsigned char *)((uintptr_t)(x) & ~(uintptr_t)(15))
```

if you want to be portable...

Comment: Some explanation please :)

Comment: @HamZa `~(uintptr_t)15` is the bitwise negated of 15, i. e. `0xffff...fff0` (it's an `uintptr_t` so that it's exactly as long as a pointer). If you bitwise AND the pointer with it, you round it down to 16s.

Answer (score 0):

try `x & 0xfffffff0` at least for 32 bit integers.

Comment: This will fail miserably on non-32-bit implementations. It isn't obliged to compile without casts to an integer either.